# No mapping found for dependency [type=com.opensymphony.xwork2.FileManagerFactory, name='default']

Tags: java, struts2

I am trying to run a struts 2, hibernate application. I can't get the application to start. I am trying to use the newest libraries if possible. I have the newest struts/hibernate in my pom.xml. Just can't get it to go in eclipse, with tomcat 8. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

These are the jars I am referencing

```
struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.23.jar
ognl-3.1.12.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.2.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-lang3-3.4.jar
log4j-api-2.7.jar
log4j-1.2.12.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar
javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
classmate-1.3.0.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
mssql-jdbc-6.2.0.jre8.jar
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
version="3.0">
 <display-name>Data Dictionary</display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>struts.xml</param-value>
     </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"> 
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>DataDictionary</groupId>
<artifactId>DataDictionary</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>DataDictionary Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.10.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0.jre8</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">

<struts>
  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
  <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="saveDescriptions" method="save" 
 class="com.joe.action.DataDictionaryAction">
        <result name="success" type="redirect">listDescriptions</result>
    </action>
    <action name="listDescriptions" method="list" class="com.joe.action.DataDictionaryAction">
        <result name="success">/save.jsp</result>
    </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```

Error console

```
ERROR Dispatcher Dispatcher initialization failed
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.DependencyException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory, name='default'] in public void com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.setObjectFactory(com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory).
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectorsForMembers(ContainerImpl.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectorsForMethods(ContainerImpl.java:116)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:90)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$1.create(ContainerImpl.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$1.create(ContainerImpl.java:71)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache$CallableCreate.call(ReferenceCache.java:155)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.internalCreate(ReferenceCache.java:79)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.get(ReferenceCache.java:123)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:468)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:507)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:505)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:560)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:505)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:188)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:906)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:75)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Update**:

when I change the param-value in my web.xml to

```
<param-value>struts.xml,struts-config.xml,struts-default.xml,struts-plugin.xml</param-value>
```

Then I get this error

```
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:906)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:75)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Parent package is not defined: struts-default - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.buildPackageContext(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:686)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:536)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:108)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you used all the right jars?

Comment: I just used maven to supply the right jars. I can add the jars it added when I get home.

Comment: Which error do you get? About filemanager or objectfactory?

Comment: Aleksandr, see my Update. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Try to remove config `init-param`.

Comment: Yes removing config init-param worked.